# asp.net mvc: .net core: how to map stored proc result set to class fields

Tags: stored-procedures, asp.net-core

I got this simple model class:

public class PrvProduct
    {

```
    [Key]
    public Int32 ProductId
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public Int64 ProductLineId;
    public String MfgPartNumber;
    public String ProductName;
    public String ProductDescription;

}
```

I'm trying to call a stored proc, using .net core, it works fine, returns a list of PrvProduct objects. problem is:  their fields are empty, unless I fill them up myself in code. ProductId is always there, not sure why (maybe because i typed there the [key] attribute?) but the rest are not.

is there a simple way to map class fields to results sets, like in ado.net (i would just do SQLDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataTable) and the MyDataTable fields will have the values by field name)... or do i have to do option 2 below every time?

Many thanks!

string sqlQuery = "EXEC Maint.GetProductList '" + sNameFilter + "'";
            //option 1: this gets no value in the fields of each PrvProduct (ProductId gets value maybe because its [key], the others don't) 
            IQueryable results = _context.Products.FromSql(sqlQuery).AsNoTracking();

```
        //option 2: this works, but... do i have to do this for every stored proc i call, every field, or is there a beter way to map class fields to returned results fields?
        List<PrvProduct> oList = new List<PrvProduct>();
        using (var command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            _context.Database.OpenConnection();

            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    // Map to your entity
                    oList.Add(new PrvProduct
                    {
                        ProductId = result.GetInt32(0),
                        ProductName = result.GetString(1)
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `_context.Products.FromSql(sqlQuery)` should work exactly how you want. If it's not, there's some issue at play that's not apparent from what you've provided here alone. My best guess is that you're running into a mapping issue. For `FromSql` to work in terms of mapping to an entity type on your context, the column types must match up with what is on your class.

Comment: I got it! the properties had to have get\set for it to work. I changed the class definition and it worked:

public class PrvProduct
    {

        [Key]
        public Int32 ProductId
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public Int32 ProductLineId
        {
            get; set;

        }
        public String MfgPartNumber
        {
            get; set;

        }
        public String ProductName
        {
            get; set;

        }
        public String ProductDescription
        {
            get; set;

        }

    }

Answer (score 1):

In EF Core, if you execute a stored procedure using one of your DbSet entities then it will map it automatically. The problem is that in many case you need to map a stored procedure to a DTO, for example, and the DTO is not part of your DbSet entities. In those cases you need to go back in time and map it manually which is a waste of time.

**In order to avoid mapping the data reader manually, I added a bunch of extension methods that do it for you.** The code is not perfect and I'm still improving it but it's good enough in most of the cases.

Once you add the extensions methods I'm gonna describe below, you can use it like this:

```
return dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<SalesReportDTO>("spGetSalesReport",
                SqlParameterBuilder.Build("customerId", customerId),
                SqlParameterBuilder.Build("dateFrom", from),
                SqlParameterBuilder.Build("dateTo", to)).ToList();
```

DatabaseFacadeExtensions: adds extensions methods to DatabaseFacade class, allowing you to call the method SqlQuery from dbContext.Database just like we used to do with Entity Framework 6.

```
    public static class DatabaseFacadeExtensions
    {
        public static List<T> SqlQuery<T>(this DatabaseFacade database, string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            return SqlQuery<T>(database, query, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);
        }

        public static List<T> SqlQuery<T>(this DatabaseFacade database, string query, CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            return SqlQuery<T>(database, query, null, commandType, parameters);
        }

        public static List<T> SqlQuery<T>(this DatabaseFacade database, string query, int? commandTimeout, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            return SqlQuery<T>(database, query, commandTimeout, CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);
        }

        public static List<T> SqlQuery<T>(this DatabaseFacade database, string query, int? commandTimeout, CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            using (var cmd = database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.CommandType = commandType;
                if (commandTimeout.HasValue)
                {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout.Value;
                }
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

                if (cmd.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                }

                try
                {
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        return reader.MapToList<T>();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

DbDataReaderExtensions: adds extensions methods to DbDataReader class so it can map the data reader to your own clases.

```
public static class DbDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static List<T> MapToList<T>(this DbDataReader dr)
    {
        var objList = new List<T>();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            bool isSingleValue = typeof(T).IsPrimitive || typeof(T) == typeof(string);
            IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = null;
            Dictionary<string, DbColumn> colMapping = null;

            if (!isSingleValue)
            {
                props = typeof(T).GetRuntimeProperties();
                colMapping = dr.GetColumnSchema()
                    .Where(x => props.Any(y => y.Name.ToLower() == x.ColumnName.ToLower()))
                    .ToDictionary(key => key.ColumnName.ToLower());
            }

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                T obj;
                if (isSingleValue)
                {
                    obj = (T)dr.GetValue(0);

                }
                else
                {
                    obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                    foreach (var prop in props)
                    {
                        string propertyName = prop.Name.ToLower();
                        if (!colMapping.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        var val = dr.GetValue(colMapping[propertyName].ColumnOrdinal.Value);
                        if (val != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            // enum property
                            if (prop.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                            {
                                prop.SetValue(obj, Enum.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, val));
                            }
                            // nullable enum property
                            if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType).IsEnum)
                            {
                                prop.SetValue(obj, Enum.ToObject(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType), val));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                prop.SetValue(obj, val);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                objList.Add(obj);
            }
        }

        return objList;
    }

    public static T MapToObject<T>(this DbDataReader dr)
    {
        var props = typeof(T).GetRuntimeProperties();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            var colMapping = dr.GetColumnSchema()
                .Where(x => props.Any(y => y.Name.ToLower() == x.ColumnName.ToLower()))
                .ToDictionary(key => key.ColumnName.ToLower());

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    var val = dr.GetValue(colMapping[prop.Name.ToLower()].ColumnOrdinal.Value);
                    prop.SetValue(obj, val == DBNull.Value ? null : val);
                }

                return obj;
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }

}
```

The next class is optional but I use to build parameters in a simpler way and it's needed in the example I described above:

```
    public class SqlParameterBuilder
    {
        public static SqlParameter Build(string name, bool? value)
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                return new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = name, Value = value.Value };
            }

            return new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = name, Value = DBNull.Value };
        }

        public static SqlParameter Build(string name, int? value)
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                return new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = name, Value = value.Value };
            }

            return new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = name, Value = DBNull.Value };
        }


        public static SqlParameter Build(string name, string value)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                return new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = name, Value = value };
            }

            return new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = name, Value = DBNull.Value };
        }

        public static SqlParameter Build(string name, DateTime? value)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                return new SqlParameter { ParameterName = name, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = value };
            }

            return new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = name, Value = DBNull.Value };
        }

        public static SqlParameter Build(string name, Guid? value)
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                return new SqlParameter { ParameterName = name, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, Value = value };
            }

            return new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = name, Value = DBNull.Value };
        }

        public static SqlParameter Build(string name, int[] values)
        {
            SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter(name, SqlDbType.Structured);
            par.TypeName = "dbo.IntParameterList";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            par.Value = dt;

            if (values != null)
            {
                foreach (int value in values.Where(p => p != 0))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(value);
                }
            }

            return par;
        }

        public static SqlParameter Build(string name, string[] values, VarcharParameterListEnum varcharParameterListType = VarcharParameterListEnum.Varchar50)
        {
            SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter(name, SqlDbType.Structured);
            switch(varcharParameterListType)
            {
                case VarcharParameterListEnum.Varchar15:
                    par.TypeName = "dbo.Varchar15ParameterList";
                    break;
                case VarcharParameterListEnum.Varchar50:
                    par.TypeName = "dbo.Varchar50ParameterList";
                    break;
                case VarcharParameterListEnum.Varchar100:
                    par.TypeName = "dbo.Varchar100ParameterList";
                    break;
                case VarcharParameterListEnum.Varchar255:
                    par.TypeName = "dbo.Varchar255ParameterList";
                    break;
                case VarcharParameterListEnum.Varchar510:
                    par.TypeName = "dbo.Varchar510ParameterList";
                    break;
            }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("textValue", typeof(string));
            par.Value = dt;

            if (values != null)
            {
                foreach (var value in values.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(value);
                }
            }

            return par;
        }

    }
```